# Set max CUDA resources

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I am wondering if it is possible to set the max GPU resources of a CUDA application? For example If I had a 4GB GPU but wanted a given application to only be able to access 2GB of it, and fail if it tries to allocate more.

Ideally this could either be set on a process level or on a CUDA context level.

Comment: There are no controls at the process level or at the CUDA context level that would allow you to do this.  You could launch a process on the GPU that simply reserved (i.e. allocated) 2GB.  That allocation would be unusable by other processes until the allocation process terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no API, process, or driver controls which allow that kind of resource management at present.