# How to change the number of CUDA cores for calculating the efficiency and scalability?

Tags: cuda

I'm new on CUDA and I would like to ask your help to know if it's possible to change the number of cores to calculate the efficiency and scalability of a program, besides modifying the kernel with the number of threads per block and blocks of threads for execution. That is, if it's assumed that efficiency and scalability are based on the number of processors and I start with 512 cores in my FERMI GPU, How could I change from 512 to 256, 128, etc. cores in order to get differents Speedup's for a given data load?? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: CUDA doesn't provide a direct method to do this.  Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427369/set-max-cuda-resources) and I'm sure there are other similar questions.  It's probably possible to occupy a single SM using careful block coding techniques, but this won't give you granularity to the CUDA cores level.

Comment: You want to reduce the number of cores, does it mean you want to deactivate part of the hardware ? Or are you referring to logics cuda threads ?

Comment: thanks for your answers, very usefull to me!!! I mean like to deactivate part of the hardware, but I understood. so is there other way to calculate efficiency and scalability on a program with a fixed number of cores?

Answer (score 3):

CUDA doesn't support that type of hardware granularity and there is no way to control cores in the way you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks!!! So, if i can not manipulate the cores to do it,  is there some method to calculate efficiency and scalability on a program with a fixed number of cores? I mean, to get varying the speedup with a fixed number of cores?

Comment: @00ivan00: Vary the amount of parallel work for a fixed number of cores, rather than vary the number of cores for a fixed amount of parallel work.