# Emulate a lower power GPU to help generate Minimum Requirments

Tags: gpu, emulation

Is it possible for me to Emulate a GPU range. I would like to find the system requirements for an application I am developing in Unity. An automated system requirements generator does not seem like a good solution as I would like to see what it runs like on specific hardware ranges (like 1060 or RX 580).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044236/downgrading-gpu-to-a-model-with-lower-capability-and-memory-for-testing?rq=1

Comment: @Aboud Nope, this is no where near the solution I'm looking for
Did you even read either question beyond the title??

Comment: Seems like the same question except the other one is for CUDA

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of "like to see what it runs like". What does that entail? As I currently understand the question, the answer is: No, not to any reasonable level of fidelity. My recommendation: build a small collection of test systems with GPUs that allow you to roughly cover the envisioned range of target systems.